# how to place a "double" formated to 6 decimal digits into a QString?

Tags: c++, qstring

I want to place a double into a QString with a format that yields 6 decimal digits.

ie.  %1.6f

This crashes with memory dump:

```
char *x = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    for(int i; i < m_iBuild; i++){
        std::fill_n(x, 20, '\0');
        sprintf(x, "%1.12f", dLog[i]);
        out << x << "\t" << msgList.at(cLog[i]) << "\n";
}
```

If I just placed dLog[i] into the stream I get scientific notation of 5 digits.

Comment: hrm, [arg](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#arg-20) or [number](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#number-2) look like candidates

Comment: And what have you done so far to achieve it?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get 888888.888888:

```
 for(int i; i < m_iBuild; i++){
        out << QString::number(dLog[i] - dLog[0], 'f', 6) << "\t" << msgList.at(cLog[i]) << "\n";
    }
```